# Display old posts if no future posts exist

Tags: query

I have a loop setup to display future posts but would like to set up an if statement where if there are no future posts, it will show a certain amount of published posts. My current query below:

```
        <?php
            query_posts('posts_per_page=5&order=ASC&post_status=future');
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You already have an `if` statement:) just make a second query.

Comment: What I would like to know is how to determine there are no future posts and in that case, post some older ones.

Comment: Your code is already doing that, that is what `if ( have_posts()` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example:

```
<?php
            query_posts('posts_per_page=5&order=ASC&post_status=future');
            if ( !have_posts() ) 
            query_posts('posts_per_page=5&order=DESC&post_status=publish');
            if( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael that got me most of the way there. This works: 
`<?php
 query_posts('posts_per_page=5&order=ASC&post_status=future');
 if ( !have_posts() ) {
 query_posts('posts_per_page=5&order=DESC&post_status=publish');
 }
 if( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>`